# App crash in com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.Trace.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I've an app crash at random when using Firebase performance 11.0.2.

```
Exception java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.Trace.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.remove (FinalizerReference.java:71)
java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize (Daemons.java:178)
java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run (Daemons.java:170)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
```

Can someone please point if the issue is in my code or in Firebase?

Comment: Hello, Firebase staff here.  It's probably a bug in Firebase Performance, but you should first try to upgrade to the latest 11.4.0.  If you want to file a bug, that's welcome. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/